# SD card not working, format not working

Tags: gparted, sd-card

My sd card in mobile was showing corrupted.
I thought to format it from my ubuntu machine.

upon clicking format nothing was happening in the system, but data was accessible in system so I copied all the data.

I tried deleting, but nothing happens.

At last I tried this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=32
```

note my sd card is sdb1

Again format isn't working.

In the system restart, I found that the computer could not load the card and the system did not start until I removed the SD card.

[image]

Upon restarting I tried to format again, and the dialog opened up.
I tried **dmesg** command while format is in progress and errors were being logged there:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 10944 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
FAT-fs (sdb1): bread failed in fat_clusters_flush
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 9176 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0 to 132, lost async page write
```

I also tried gparted but similar errors were seen.
Is there any way, I could get my SD card back?

Comment: Some cards and usb sticks default to read only if they are damaged, power fluctuations etc, If you can read but not write (or format) then this is a strong possibility (P.S. Please don't post screenshots, copy / paste is good enough)

Comment: This is a screenshot on system start, how can one copy data from there?
how can I recover my SD card?

Comment: Anyone out there?  Please help me

Comment: Can you still read the data in the card?